# Laravel Cashier IncompletePayment handling

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I try to implement a stripe payment to my project. I use Laravel cashier for single charge and for subscriptions also. My problem is the incompletepayment handling for sca cards.

I have done with this:

```
try {
            $customer->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
            $customer->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
            $charge = $customer->charge($paynow * 100, $paymentMethod, [
                'currency' => "gbp",
            ]);

       } catch (\Exception $e) {

        if ($e instanceof \Laravel\Cashier\Exceptions\PaymentActionRequired) {
            return redirect()->route('cashier.payment', [$e->payment->id, 'redirect' => route('bookingconfirmation')]);
        } else {
            dump($e); die;
        } // continue
```

After a successful payment confirmation the code is finished with the redirection, but I still want to processing some data, so the code only reach the // continue part if we use normal cards without SCA. I want to save some data to database but I don't want to use the charge.successed webhook for this. Any advise?

Comment: "but I don't want to use the charge.successed webhook for this" why not? you kind of have to as far as I understand how Stripe works, you use the webhook to update your database. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-fulfillment

Comment: Well let's say I will use the webhooks. But how can I manage that scenario, when on the cashier confirmation page, the Customer simply click the back button before he make the authentication process, so then I don't receive any webhook. So the problem we can't change the button where redirect based on results.